# WebMvcAutoConfiguration with multiple external EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue in the process of migrating an existing spring web application to Spring Boot 1.5.13. I've handled almost everything, but I can't managed to have the good persistence unit injected to WebMvcAutoConfiguration. I actually have 3 different entity manager factory that are imported from the classpath (provided as .xml file by 3 different internal libraries, I have no way to change them). Each of them is splitted in this way:

```
<sqe-db:jpa-emf database-definition-name="db-name" embedded-datasource="false"/>
```

and

```
<bean id="transaction-mnanager-name" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="jpa-lib-name" />
    </bean>
```

The datasources configuration is provided by tomcat at the moment, but I will externalize them to application.properties for the dev environment

After my migration, I didn't find any way to specify the right bean to WebMvcAutoConfiguration, and this is leading to the following error:

```
Method requestMappingHandlerMapping in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - jpa-lib1-name1: defined in null
    - jpa-lib1-name2: defined in null
    - jpa-lib1-name3: defined in null
```

My goal at this point is to have the following configuration in place:

- have the application both runnable as a SpringApplication and deployable as a WAR (and I think I already did it properly)
- having a way to use Spring Boot autoconfiguration for web apps, even with multiple entity factory in the classpath
- use my own datasources for the "dev" profile, but leave the tomcat one for the other environment.

my requisites are, more or less:
 - minimize the changes needed to the existing application
 - continue to use the .xml provided by the libraries

An easy option would be to rewrite the configuration, using a more modern annotation driven configuration, but I would prefer to stick to the existing implementation, so that I don't have to change it when a new library is released.

Any way to declare the @Primary bean without touching the existing xml file?

Any ideas, or different approaches are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

After a good night of sleep, I was able to find the easiest of the solution.

I added this to my configuration class:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("name-of-default-factory")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
@Primary
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

And it will now have the primary bean correctly injected.